# react hook serveral call and setState other value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very curious about this phenomenon.
I use useEffect serveral time, and setState other value.
but It's only been shot twice on the console.
useEffect many calls, but only twice on the console.
Anyone who knows why, please help..

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Test() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(prev => prev + 1)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(prev => prev -1)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(prev => 0)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(prev => prev + 1)
  }, [])

  console.log('render', value)
  return(
    <div>promise</div>
  )
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: Setting state is batched. Therefore you'll get one log when the app mounts, then another after all the state changes are applied.

Comment: Great answer but not complete - the state updates are batched only when they are triggered synchronosly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `setState` is triggered synchronously (as in your example), React batches the state updates and reduces the number of component re-renders.

Your component is rendered initially with `value=0`, and then with `value=1` as all of the above set state are batched into one update.

I challange you to wrap each `setValue` with a `setTimeout(..., 0)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

try the below modified code and see the console....

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let r = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("incrementing");
    setValue((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("decrementing");
    setValue((prev) => prev - 1);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("initailze");
    setValue((prev) => 0);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("again incrementing");
    setValue((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, []);

  console.log("render", value);

  return <div>promise</div>;
}
```

you might see like...

```
render 0

incrementing 

decrementing 

initailze

again incrementing

render 1
```

now let me explain what heppens here. when your app first time render it logs the effect

> render 0

and now all four useEffects run one by one

> incrementing
>
> decrementing
>
> initailze
>
> again incrementing

and remember that setState(in your case setValue) function in the event handler and useEffect hook runs asynchronusly and thus batch all the updates into one to make it more performant. that's why, instead of getting four successive render you get only one render with logging your final state value

> render 1